# How to make sure the logged message goes to a new line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make my own logging system because I don't like Python's one, but I ran into a small problem. Whenever I log two or more things, only the last log is written. Example - I log 'code initialized' at the start of the program. Then, I log 'exiting'. The result in the log file is only 'exiting' How do I fix this? Here is my code.

File 1.

```
from functions import *
from variables import *

try:
    open('key.txt', "r")
    key = True
except FileNotFoundError:
    key = False

if check_internet():
    x = status_boot[0]
elif not check_internet():
    x = status_boot[1]

log("archer initialized")

if key:
    print("archer status: " + x)
elif not key:
    print(status_boot[4])
```

File 2.

```
from datetime import datetime
from variables import *
import requests


def time():
    now = datetime.now()
    return now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")


def check_internet():
    timeout = 5
    try:
        _ = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
        return True
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        return False


def log(m):
    write = open('archerlog.txt', 'w+')
    return write.write(f'[{time()}] archer: {m}\n')
```

File 3.

```
url = "http://www.google.com/"

status_boot = ["online", "offline", "key invalid", "error", "Error: Key not accessible!"]

x = status_boot[3]
```

Comment: `w+` erases existing file contents.

Comment: make it `open("filename", "a")`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I'm still learning operating with files with Python so this helped a lot.